# read from .txt C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm having some trouble with C language..

I have one file txt with various lines in the form:

```
F   65  S   4   1   139.56  3704.26
```

and my program:

```
p = fopen("dados.txt", "r");

if ( p == NULL) {
    printf("\n\nNao foi possivel abrir o arquivo.\n");
    exit(1);
}else{
      while ( !feof(p) ){
      fscanf(p,"%c %d %c %d %d %f %f",
          &sexo,&idade,&estadoCivil,&numFilhos,&freq,&mediaGasto,&mediaSalarial);

      printf("%c %d %c %d %d %f %f\n",
          sexo,idade,estadoCivil,numFilhos,freq,mediaGasto,mediaSalarial);
      }
```

the return is:

[image]

looks bad...

if i change in fscanf: %c to %f

the return is:

[image]

looks great, but the variable idade is always 0... :S

wtf i have to do?

Comment: Do you declare the variable before you use it?

Comment: What is the code after you make the change, I don't get why you would change `%c` to `%f`?

Comment: You have to check the result of `fscanf()`; it will tell you whether it read all the values it was supposed to.  Also, you run into a problem with the newline; the `%c` on the second iteration will pick up the newline from the previous line.  Generally, don't use `fscanf()`; it is hard to use correctly.  Use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` instead; much easier to control and get correct.

Comment: my bad, the change is %c ti %s

Comment: Note that `feof` only returns a true value **after** it's tried reading past the end of a file, not once you've read up to the end of the file. It can cause loops to run 1 extra time - as it does for you if you look at the last 2 lines of your output. Consider checking the return value of `fscanf` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the newline to your `scanf` call:

```
  fscanf(p,"%c %d %c %d %d %f %f\n",
      &sexo,&idade,&estadoCivil,&numFilhos,&freq,&mediaGasto,&mediaSalarial);
```

Without the newline in `scanf`, the first line will be correct, but the following line assigns the newline from the input to `sexo`.